# Unable to run angular application using ng server getting Module not found

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, primeng

I unzipped a angular application and did a `npm install` it worked well and later did `ng serve` but when i did i got the below issue

[image: issue::]

I install `node-sass` and cleared node cache also and deleted node_nodules & deleted package-lock.json and re installed again issue still persists.

I am using `primeng 8.0,boostrap5.1.1,angular8,gojs`

local development setup info using

Angular 12 , Node 14

**angular.json**

```
"projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/draggableLinks",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"

            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

**package.json**

```
"version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "gojs": "^2.0.16",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you run `npm install` before , `ng serve` ?

Comment: @Maher yes the problem is in one system it is running good and in another system it is giving issues . Tried in 8 systems 5 worked and in 3 it gave issues and config on those systems are same

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying stylesheet urls in *angular.json* by removing './' as below.

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
          ]
```